# How to remove partial path from Get-Location output?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to write a custom prompt for PowerShell and I was wondering how I would filter out the 1...n directories in the output of `Get-Location`.

```
function prompt {
  "PS " + $(get-location) + "> "
}
```

So, if the path is too long I would like to omit some of the directories and just display `PS...blah\blah>` or something. I tried `(get-container) - 1` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you thinking about only show the last x directories?. Split-Path is an easy way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ansgar Wiechers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30958912/3829407) will give you the last directory but if you want a way to do multiple directories at the end of the filepath (using the triple dot notation) you can [cast the directory path](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/10/29/dynamic-casting.aspx) to a uri and then just get and join the [segments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments(v=vs.110).aspx):

```powershell
function prompt {
    $curPath = pwd
    $pathUri = ([uri] $curPath.ToString())

    if ($pathUri.Segments.Count -le 3) {
        "PS {0}>" -f $curPath
    } else {
        "PS...{0}\{1}>" -f $pathUri.Segments[-2..-1].trim("/") -join ""
    }
}
```

Or using just a string (no uri cast)

```powershell
function prompt {
        $curPath = pwd
        $pathString = $curPath.Tostring().split('\') #Changed; no reason for escaping

        if ($pathString.Count -le 3) {
            "PS {0}>" -f $curPath
        } else {
            "PS...{0}\{1}>" -f $pathString[-2..-1] -join ""
        }
    }

$a = prompt
Write-Host $a
```

Then just change *-2* to whatever you want to be the first directory and *-le 3* to match. I typically use the uri cast when I have to run stuff through a browser or over connections to Linux machines (as it uses "/" as a path separator) but there is no reason to not use the string method for normal operations.

Comment: Always forget the URI cast

Comment: @Matt Thanks, saw that but was adding a string method so hadn't gotten to editing that in :)

Comment: I might be wrong but is your "string" code flawed since you are using the string method split. It does not support regular expressions and you are matching _two_ slashes

Comment: @Matt Tested it on my system and it works, just escaped the backslash out of habit (cause of regex) but split sees that as the string `\\` because it is in double quotes - changed to single now as there is no reason to escape

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Split-Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849809.aspx) with the `-Leaf` parameter if you want just the last element of a path:

```psh
function prompt {
  "PS {0}> " -f (Split-Path -Leaf (Get-Location))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to make a more dynamic function. I do just basic string manipulation. You could do some logic nesting `Split-Path` but the string manipulation approach is just so much more terse. Since what you want to be returned wont be a fully validated path I feel better offering this solution.

```psh
Function Get-PartialPath($path, $depth){
    If(Test-Path $path){
        "PS {0}>" -f (($path -split "\\")[-$depth..-1] -join "\")
    } else {
        Write-Warning "$path is not a valid path"
    }
}
```

Sample Function call

```
Get-PartialPath C:\temp\folder1\sfg 2
PS folder1\sfg>
```

So you can use this simple function. Pass is a string for the path. Assuming it is valid then it will carve up the path into as many trailing chunks as you want. We use `-join` to rebuild it. If you give a `$depth` number that is too high the whole path will be returned. So if you only wanted to have 3 folders being shown setting the `$depth` for 3.